# WooCommerce: Display SKU number in admin side Order listing page custom column

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, orders, sku, wordpress-admin

I have added a custom column in Woocommerce admin side order listing page to display Ordered item Products name and total Quantity like this -> [http://prntscr.com/p11rdl] by using the following code:

```
add_filter('manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'misha_order_items_column' );
function misha_order_items_column( $order_columns ) {
    $order_columns['order_products'] = "Qty-Products Name-SKU";
    return $order_columns;
}
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'misha_order_items_column_cnt' );
function misha_order_items_column_cnt( $colname ) {
  global $the_order; // the global order object
  if( $colname == 'order_products' ) {
    // get items from the order global object
    $order_items = $the_order->get_items();
    if ( !is_wp_error( $order_items ) ) {
      foreach( $order_items as $order_item ) {
        echo $order_item['quantity'] .' × <a href="' . admin_url('post.php?post=' . $order_item['product_id'] . '&action=edit' ) . '" target="_blank">'. $order_item['name'] .'</a><br />';
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Now I also want to display ordered product SKU number after the product name. So anyone have solution for this then please provide help me.

Thank you,
Ketan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace with follows code snippets to add SKU -

```
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'misha_order_items_column_cnt' );
function misha_order_items_column_cnt( $colname ) {
  global $the_order; // the global order object
  if( $colname == 'order_products' ) {
    // get items from the order global object
    $order_items = $the_order->get_items();
    if ( !is_wp_error( $order_items ) ) {
      foreach( $order_items as $order_item ) {
        $product = $order_item->get_product();
        // product checking
        $sku = ( $product && $product->get_sku() ) ? ' - ' . $product->get_sku() : '';
        echo $order_item['quantity'] .' × <a href="' . admin_url('post.php?post=' . $order_item['product_id'] . '&action=edit' ) . '" target="_blank">'. $order_item['name'] . '</a>'. $sku . '<br />';
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you @itzmekhokan. Yes, above code working and display SKU number after the product name. Can you please show SKU number after the product anchor tag?

Comment: @Ketan I just updated above code as per your comments. Please check it.

Comment: You should better use directly `$product = $order_item->get_product();` as if it is a product variations that has its own SKU, the parent variable product SKU will be displayed instead.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, thanks for correcting me. Yes, its best way to get product object for an order item.

Comment: Thank you @itzmekhokan for your support.

Comment: Hello  @itzmekhokan, After adding the above code I am facing one issue in the admin side order listing page. Please review this -> http://prntscr.com/p13ihq screenshot. In order listing page top right side "Screen Options" and order pagination not working. So can you please look into this issue.

Comment: @Ketan, I just check the above code in my end and I do not find such an issue. So you please double check it that issue coming from the above code.

Comment: @itzmekhokan: Yes I have tested. That issues coming from your above code. When I have added old without SKU number display code then I can't see issue.

Comment: @Ketan, you can add extra checking if sku is available only then it will append with product name. But as per me the above code is perfect.

Comment: @itzmekhokan: The issue coming when we add `$product->get_sku()` code inside the for each loop echo line. For your clarification inside my website some old orders products now not available on the website. So many be for this need to do add any condition for SKU? Also many be inside some products SKU number not available.

Comment: @Ketan, thanks for your clarification. I updated above code snippet with product checking. Please check it. I think it will solve the issue.

Comment: @itzmekhokan: Thanks again. The updated code condition fixed the issue. :)

Comment: Thank you so much I've found this thread extremely helpful, I couldn't thank the original poster enough as well the help from @itzmekhokan and various other contributors, this community is awesome.

What I'm needing now is to add product shelve location straight after SKU. I have the below code for location fields but not sure how to amend to the code above to make it work. I'm new to coding in general, but have found snippets of code and made it work so far.

Your help and guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much I've found this thread extremely helpful, I couldn't thank the original poster enough as well the help from @itzmekhokan and various other contributors, this community is awesome.

What I'm needing now is to add product shelve location straight after SKU.
I have the below code for location fields but not sure how to amend to the code above to make it work. I'm new to coding in general, but have found snippets of code and made it work so far.

Your help and guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
// Add Location field
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_stock_fields', 'product_shelf' ); 
function product_shelf() {
    global $woocommerce, $post;
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id'          => 'product_shelf',
            'placeholder' => 'Enter product shelf location here',
            'label'       => 'Shelf Location',
            'description' => 'Shelf location of product',
            'desc_tip'    => 'true',
        )
    );
}

// Save location data
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'product_shelf_data' );
function product_shelf_data( $post_id ) {   
    // grab the location from $_POST
    $product_shelf = isset( $_POST[ 'product_shelf' ] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'product_shelf' ] ) : '';

    // grab the product
    $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );

    // save the location using WooCommerce built-in functions
    $product->update_meta_data( 'product_shelf', $product_shelf_data ); 
    $product->save();   
}
```